# ng-bootstrap's css folder does not exist

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm new to angular and trying to use bootstrap 4 in conjunction with angular. First i installed ng-bootstrap like follow:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

And some other related stuff in `app.module.ts`

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
NgbModule.forRoot()
```

And add some style into `.angular-cli.json` (put following code into `styles` array)

```
"../node_modules/@bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Everything work as expected but style!
I realize that `dist` sub-folder does not exist in '../node_modules/@bootstrap/' address.
I also tried to build the project using `ng build`, But it still doesn't exist. Note that `"outDir": "dist"` is checked in `.angular-cli.json` file.
Am i miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ng-Bootstrap` contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap’s markup and CSS. As a result, it's not dependent on jQuery or Bootstrap’s JavaScript
 but it requires Bootstrap's 4 css to be added in your project. you need to Install it explicitly via:
`npm install bootstrap@4  --save`
and add the file paths to the styles array in file .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

Comment: No, as this `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started` link mentioned:"Should I add bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js to my project?
No, the goal of ng-bootstrap is to completely replace JavaScript implementation for components. Nor should you include other dependencies like jQuery or popper.js. It is not necessary and might interfere with ng-bootstrap code. "

Comment: My bad, but u still need bootstrap css to be added in your styles array,I have edited my ans

Comment: @Viskas Yes but **I realize that dist sub-folder does not exist in '../node_modules/@bootstrap/' address.**

Comment: Check  thoroughly after executing  above stated  command  subfolder must exist in`../node_modules/bootstrap/dist` what's `/@bootstrap/' address`

Comment: @Viskas because i don't have `bootstrap` folder, but instead '@bootstrap' folder does exist. On the other hand, my guess is, bootstrap css should be installed separately (also it doesn't mentioned in documents).

Comment: yes it must be installed separately   jQuery or Bootstrap’s JavaScript is not required but Bootstrap’s  css is required.

Comment: @Viskas so why not put it as answer? ;-D

Comment: @Viskas Yessssss

Comment: sorry my bad. i didn't realize that you had updated your answer ;-D